# how to configure HTTPS and HTTP binding for Ajax Enabled WCF web service

Tags: ajax, wcf, sharepoint-2010, https, wcf-binding

I encountered an errror during the accessing of my web service in https site.
i think this is a configuration error because its looking for an https binding.

here is the web.config of the web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<services>
  <service name="WebService.ListViewWebService" behaviorConfiguration="WebService.ListViewWebServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address=""
              behaviorConfiguration="WebService.ListViewWebServiceAjaxBehavior"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="WebService.IListViewWebService"/>
    <endpoint address="https://win-d741qhlbivf:13241/services/DPT/_vti_bin/DPT.WebService/ListViewWebService.svc"
              behaviorConfiguration="WebService.ListViewWebServiceAjaxBehavior1"
              binding="webHttpsBinding"
              contract="WebService.IListViewWebService2"/>
     <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />         
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBinding">
            <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="webHttpsBinding">
            <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebService.ListViewWebServiceAjaxBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>

  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebService.ListViewWebServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior> 

  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

thanks for the help in advance.

Also, I am not sure if this has something to do with the issue but the web application hosted in a cloud environment...do i need a special configuration for that?...

thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

One of my tutorials will help you:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-programmatically-configure-ssl.html

The tutorial starts with the declarative configuration and then shows how to create binding/endpoints programatically.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I followed your steps in your blog, but i'm getting the same error:

Comment: the error is: There is no endpoint behavior named 'WebService.ListViewWebServiceAjaxBehavior1'. (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\isapi\webservice\web.config line 11)

Comment: The error is precise as it only could be. There's no endpoint with such name in your config - the name in your config lacks "1" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This config will respond to requests in HTTP and HTTPS , note that the ports are different and have to match what the host is expecting (in this case it happens to be iis)

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />

        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>



<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />

    <services>
        <service name="KPIGetter_Library.KPIGetter">

            <endpoint address="" 
                    behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehaviour"
                    binding="webHttpBinding" 
                    bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"
                    contract="KPIGetter_Library.IKpiGetter" />


            <endpoint address="" 
                    behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehaviour"
                    binding="webHttpBinding" 
                    bindingConfiguration="webHttpsBindingWithJsonP"
                    contract="KPIGetter_Library.IKpiGetter" />

            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://hodbd05:8000/kpigetter" />
                    <add baseAddress="https://hodbd05:8001/kpigetter" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>

            <behavior name="restfulBehaviour">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>

        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>

    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
                     <security mode="None" />
                </binding>

                <binding name="webHttpsBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
                     <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

An important issue is that you should use webHttpBinding and not the basicHttpBinding for ajax-enabled WCF services.

A simple working example is found here: [Scott's blog on asp.net](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/wcf-bindings-needed-for-https)